# grab git repo from multiple sources in Yocto recipe

Tags: download, yocto

I am trying to retrieve sources from multiple git repos in a Yocto recipe. I used

```
SRC_URI = "git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision> \
           git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision> \
           file://<some file to grab>"
```

but it reports error that {WORKDIR}/git folder can't be found.

```
ROR: Function failed: Fetcher failure: Fetch command failed with exit code 128, output:
| shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
| shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
| fatal: Could not get current working directory: No such file or directory
```

It seems like after fetcher downloaded the first git repo, it removes content in {WORKDIR}/git to prepare for a second git repo download. Thus creating the "No directory found" error.

I tested and if only 1 git repo + files protocol fetcher can perform correctly.

Any idea how to grab source codes from multiple git repositories?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem and found that subdir and name didn't work, but `destsuffix=<somename>` worked. As far as I know this is not documented but can be understood from the bitbake fetch code. Example like airfishey:

```
SRC_URI = "git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision>;destsuffix=first_repo \
           git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision>;destsuffix=second_repo \
           file://<some file to grab>"
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried adding `subdir=` to your git lines?

Something like this?

```
SRC_URI = "git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision>;subdir=first_repo \
           git://<git_repo_uri>;protocol=ssh;rev=<revision>;subdir=second_repo \
           file://<some file to grab>"
```

It looks like there was a bug filed against this functionality at some point (https://bugzilla.yoctoproject.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6562), so your mileage may vary depending on what version of Yocto you are using.

Comment: Thanks airfishey! I am using Yocto 2.0 so I think the bug is fixed. Unfortunately after adding subdir parameter I still get the same error.

Comment: I get an error as well.  I wonder why anyone would down vote a legimate question like this?